# Adding linebreaks in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, linebreaks

Is it possible to turn this:

```
1 My old house 2 My new house 3 My blue house 4 My funhouse
```

into:

```
1 My old house
2 My new house
3 My blue house
4 My funhouse
```

using Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

Open Replace dialog, select "Extended" in Search mode, then replace house with house\n